# Is it possible to write something as complex as `print!` in a pure Rust macro?

Tags: rust, code-generation, rust-macros

I am starting out learning Rust macros, but the documentation is somewhat limited. Which is fine — they're an expert feature, I guess. While I can do basic code generation, implementation of traits, and so on, some of the built-in macros seem well beyond that, such as the various print macros, which examine a string literal and use that for code expansion.

I looked at [the source for `print!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.26.0/src/libstd/macros.rs) and it calls another macro called `format_args`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be built in "pure Rust"  the comment just says "compiler built-in."

Is it possible to write something as complex as `print!` in a pure Rust macro? If so, how would it be done?

I'm actually interested in building a "compile time trie" -- basically recognizing certain fixed strings as "keywords" fixed at compile time. This would be performant (probably) but mostly I'm just interested in code generation.

Comment: The official documentation may be "somewhat limited", but have you looked at [the little book of Rust macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/index.html)?

Comment: @Jmb no, that's new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`format_args` is implemented in the compiler itself, in the libsyntax_ext crate. The name is registered in the [`register_builtins` function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e0635188ed30e083245482218a0de9237f14ce90/src/libsyntax_ext/lib.rs#L129), and the code to process it has its entry point in the [`expand_format_args` function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1e504d301c07f84630ff0e35f10d2d69688887d6/src/libsyntax_ext/format.rs#L679).

Macros that do such detailed syntax processing cannot be defined using the `macro_rules!` construct. They can be defined with a [procedural macro](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/doc/unstable-book/src/language-features/proc-macro.md); however, this feature is currently unstable (can only be used with the nightly compiler and is subject to sudden and unannounced changes) and rather sparsely documented.

Answer (score 2):

Rust macros cannot parse string literals, so it's not possible to create a direct Rust equivalent of `format_args!`.

What you could do is to use a macro to transform the function-call-like syntax into something that represents the variadic argument list in the Rust type system in some way (say, as a heterogeneous single-linked list, or a builder type).  This can then be passed to a regular Rust function, along with the format string.  But you will not be able to implement compile-time type checking of the format string this way.

Comment: If this is so, then how does (e.g.) diesel work? It seems to generate quite extensive code for a schema from a single macro invocation, which seems to even talk to the database to get that information. Yet diesel is not part of rust -- right?

Comment: It uses custom `derive`, which allows you to generate Rust code (by writing Rust code), but that takes structs/enums/unions as input. So it's still not powerful enough to implement something like `format_args!`.